# How to handle user login session and use the same session/user for all the task in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to run login script once and whenever I run it again it would not ask me for the login.

please help me how to handle this case in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Visit Selenium documentation Guideline [**Generating application state**](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/guidelines_and_recommendations/generating_application_state/) It is mentioned there

> A method should be created to gain access to the AUT* (e.g. using an API to login and set a cookie)

You can write a method to save all your cookies after login. Now use those same cookies in test where it require login.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.somesite.com/login/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElementById("email").sendKeys("someemail@gmail.com");
driver.findElementById("pass").sendKeys("pass@312");
driver.findElementById("send2").click();

// after successful login get cookies and store in a map for further use
Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
Map<String, Object> cookieMap = new HashMap<>();
cookieMap.put("myCookies", cookies);
driver.quit();

// some other testcase which require auto login
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.somesite.com");
    
// get store cookies and add them after refresh the page you will see user automatically get logged in
Set<Cookie> storeCookies = (Set<Cookie>) cookieMap.get("myCookies");
storeCookies.forEach(cookie -> driver.manage().addCookie(cookie));
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Please Note, I've written all the code in single file you need to manage this as per your framework. e.g This Cookie Map should be accessible in all your test classes.